# Is writing HTML values the same as writing Javascript into HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, button

For my project I am not allowed to write any JavaScript into my HTML according to my teacher. That would mean that I am not allowed to write features like onClick in my HTML. I want to check a answer with the if statement by giving my buttons value's, but isn't that also seen as writing JavaScript into HTML?

I know the best thing to do would be contact my mentor, but I want to know your answer/opinion on this.

Comment: We can't know how your teacher intends their rule to be interpreted, and opinions are off-topic here.

Comment: Into the HTML isn't the same as no js at all. It doesn't mean you can't have an external js script. So put everything you need in a js script, load it and activate with "onload()". You there can bind click handlers to buttons etc

Answer (score 1):

you can use JS function to get elements from the HTML such as `document.getElementById` or `document.querySelector` and bind them an event listener.

you can read more about on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document)